# OpenCV>> Structure from motion>> Bundle adjustment using BundleAdjusterReproj

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

OpenCV has built-in bundle adjustment modules ( eg. BundleAdjusterReproj ), these use [MatchesInfo](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/stitching/doc/matching.html) object to indicate the difference/change between one image to the next, digging through the code seems that [MatchesInfo](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/stitching/doc/matching.html) struct is using a Homography matrix ( assuming a planar scene ) and not a fundamental/essential matrix ( non planar scene ), having that said, does OpenCV bundle adjustment modules are suitable for SFM ( non planner scenes ), hence, can I simply set 'MatchesInfo::H' to the Fundamental/Essential matrix, OR, should I implement the Re-projection algorithm my-self ?

Comment: I could not work it out either. Wish it was well documented... it implements Levenberg-Marquardt by the way.

Comment: I've been struggling with this too. However I don't believe that this module should work properly for SfM due to the thing that you have also noticed - it uses homography thus planar scene is assumed. SfM requires depth in the scene. Otherwise you will get a nearly flat model, which is simply useless. I recently stumbled upon the cv::LevMarqSparse and the following blog - http://ardrone-ailab-u-tokyo.blogspot.de/2012/11/opencv-levmarqsparse-class-for-sparse_13.html The guy even provides sample code (see YouTube video too). Note that the sample code uses a generated set of points and views.

Comment: If you want robust bundle adjustment I suggest g2o or Google's Ceres Solver. They will require more learning though.